# java, write to file, unicode

Tags: java, кодировка, filewriter

У меня возникла проблема

Есть массив `byte[]`, в котором лежат 6 байт: `{-23,-99,38,122,16,0};`
Я их записываю в файл:

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(encodedStringText)));
writer.write(Arrays.toString(encString));
writer.close();
```

После этого размер файла вместо положенных 6 становится 26.
Затем я пытаюсь считать, если записывать информацию в `String`, получаю те самые 6 первоначальных байт, но при попытке перевести в байты получаю 26 непонятных байт. Считываю так:

```
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(encodedStringText)));
StringBuilder stringBuilder1 = new StringBuilder();
while (reader.ready())
    stringBuilder1.append(reader.readLine());
byte[] decArray = stringBuilder1.toString().getBytes();
```

Результат: `{91,45,50,23,.....(26)}`.
В чем проблема?
Использовал различные кодировки: utf-8, utf-16, win1251, cp1251 и т.д., не помогло.

UPD.
Встает вопрос, мне необходимо работать с **char** или же **String**, поэтому я и пытался считывать через **BufferedReader**. После того, как получил строку - нужно разбить ее на символы а символы на байты, в эл-тах строки значения те же, что были записаны в качестве байт, но когда пытаюсь перезапись строку в массив байт, то получается фигня. Что же, насчет записи в файл - все получилось и с размером все устаканилось, а как тогда правильно считать с файла?

```
 reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(encodedStringText)));
 StringBuilder stringBuilder1 = new StringBuilder();
 while (reader.ready()    
      stringBuilder1.append(reader.readLine());
 byte[] decArray = stringBuilder1.toString().getBytes();
```

пытаюсь считывать так, опять проблема с тем, что получается в массиве байт

Comment: На "Stack Overflow на русском" вопросы принято задавать только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь "[Stack Overflow на английском](https://stackoverflow.com/)".

Comment: как-то можно обновить тему или же перенести ее на английскую версию сайта, а то ограничение на публикацию новых постов...

Comment: Нажмите ссылку "править" под вашим вопросом и отредактируйте его.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Writer` и `Reader` предназначены для работы с символами и со строками, с байтами же удобнее использовать непосредственно `OutputStream` и `InputStream`, см пример:

```
@Test
public void test4() throws Exception
{
    byte[] array = {-23, -99, 38, 122, 16, 0};

    String fileName = "/tmp/test4.tmp"; // замените на ваш файл
    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
    fout.write(array);
    fout.close();

    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(fileName);
    byte[] buf = new byte[0x100]; // буфер для чтения
    int count = fin.read(buf);
    fin.close();
    buf = Arrays.copyOf(buf, count); // копируем прочитанные байты

    assertArrayEquals(array, buf); // сравниваем с оригиналом
}
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, с записью разобрался) Доп вопрос:  а если мне нужно считывать строку а записывать байты? Комбинирую bufferreader и FOS все равно строка не та, что нужно

Comment: не совсем понятен доп.вопрос. добавьте код теста с пометкой где сравнивается считанная строка с ожидаемой.

Comment: заранее извиняюсь, не знаю, как код в нормальном виде в комменты вставлять + еще и кол-во символ ограничено

Comment: в комменты код вставлять и не надо. код надо добавить к вопросу, если он туда подходит по смыслу, если же нет, то лучше вынести в отдельный вопрос. подумайте о людях которые столкнуться с подобной проблемой и будут искать ответ, вряд ли будет удобно перечитывать все комменты.